# XMLWrite output a file to same directory as php script

Tags: php, mysql, save, xmlwriter

Hello here I'm once again. After my last question [XML parsing error (RESOLVED) XML Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376106/xml-parsing-error-resolved-xml-sample) which really helped me to learn more. I'm running against another brick wall.

My question:
What I need to do is to write an .xml file in the same directory where my php document is. So when i execute the script it should automatic save an .xml file to the directory where the php file is. Is this possible and how?

Currently I'm trying to output the file using the openURI but when I'm doing that I'm getting the following error(translated from Dutch):

The fun thing is if I use php://output it shows all of it correctly in the browser.

```
XML-Parse Error: no element found
Location: xml.php
Rownumber 1, column 1:
```

Code:

```
<?php
    //SELECTEER ALLES VAN DATABASE PROJECTEN
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projecten ORDER BY id";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    //BEGIN XML
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI('file.xml');
    $xml->setIndentString ( '&#09;' );
    $xml->startDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8', 'no' );
    $xml->setIndent(true);

    //FUNCTIE VOOR MAKKELIJKER INVOEREN
    function addNode( $xml, $NodeName, $Value ) {
    $xml->startElement( $NodeName );
    $xml->writeCData( $Value );
    $xml->endElement();      
    }

   //START HOOFD ELEMENT
   $xml->startElement('projecten');

    //WHILE LOOP DOOR DATABASE
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

            //START PROJECT
            $xml->startElement('project');
            $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row['id']);

                addNode( $xml, "id", $row["id"] );
                addNode( $xml, "projectnaam", $row['projectnaam'] );
                addNode( $xml, "status", $row['status'] );
                addNode( $xml, "klantnaam", $row['klantnaam'] );
                addNode( $xml, "startdatum", $row['startdatum'] );
                addNode( $xml, "eindddatum", $row['einddatum'] );

            //EIND PROJECT
            $xml->endElement();
    }

    //EINDE HOOFD ELEMENT
    $xml->endElement();

    //EINDE DOCUMENT
    $xml->endDocument(); 
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $xml->flush();
?>
```

Thanks in advance, once again...

Comment: Did you try searching? You can use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write to a file.

Comment: I'm sorry Amal Murali if this might be a newb question. I am totally new towards PHP mySQL and so on. So i'm sorry if I can't find a solution on my own..

Comment: ` file_put_contents('output.xml', $xml); ` Should do the trick then? I've tried it multiple time but it isn't outputting a file?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use fopen .Here is my code-

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data`";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->setIndent(true);
function addNode($xml,$NodeName,$Value){
    $xml->startElement($NodeName);
    $xml->writeCData($Value);
    $xml->endElement();

}
$xml->startElement('Details');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $xml->startElement('Data');
    $xml->writeAttribute('date',$row['date']);
    addNode($xml,"Id",$row["id"]);
    addNode($xml,"age",$row["age"]);
    addNode($xml,"Name",$row["name"]);
    $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();

$content = $xml->flush();

$fp = fopen("filetobesaved.xml",'w');
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $content;
?>
```

This code will create a generate an xml file and save it in same folder where you php code file is rendered and will save it with the name filetobesaved.xml .Here `w`  will create the file if it does not exist- `$fp = fopen("filetobesaved.xml",'w');` and if you want to create a new directory and save your .xml file into it then you can do it this way-

```
$filename = 'D:/foldertobecreated/filetobesaved.xml';
$dirname = dirname($filename);
if (!is_dir($dirname))
{
    mkdir($dirname, 0755, true);
}

$fp = fopen("$dirname\\filetobesaved.xml",'w');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to give the absolute path to openURI with __ DIR __:

```
$xml->openURI(__DIR__ . 'file.xml');
```